# Why does this ASP.NET Core Web Application not run from the D: Drive?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am new to ASP.New Core and Angular. As one of my starting projects, I created a template project in Visual Studio 2017 as follows:

File -> New -> Project...
Visual C# -> ASP.NET Core Web Application -> Angular -> Uncheck "Configure for HTTPS"

I have a D: drive mapped on my computer, and I created this project there; but when I go to run it, I get an error. I created the exact same project in my C: drive, and it runs as expected. So, why does it work in the C: drive but not the D: drive?

The error message I get when running from the D: drive is:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "D:\\Documents\\Visual Studio Projects\\WebApplication1\\WebApplication1\\ClientApp".

Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "D:\\Documents\\Visual Studio Projects\\WebApplication1\\WebApplication1\\ClientApp".

at Object.resolve (C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:141:11)
at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect-legacy.js:153:40)
at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
at C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:99:19
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Observable.toPromise (C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:97:16)
at ServeCommand.initialize (C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:67:96)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:11)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! WebApplication1@0.0.0 start: `ng serve "--port" "51076"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the WebApplication1@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

))

System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)
```

Comment: Do you have `node_modules` folder inside clientapp folder? If not. cd to clientapp folder and run `npm i`. Then run app again.

Comment: This did the trick; thanks!